# Перегрузка операторов ввода и вывода из потока в шаблонном классе

Tags: c++, перегрузка-операторов, шаблоны-с++

Доброго времени суток. Пишу свой вектор. В нём надо перегрузить вышеназванные операторы.
Vector.h

```
class Vector
{
    // ...
    template<typename T1> friend std::ostream&  operator<< (std::ostream&, Vector<T>&);
    // ...
};

template<typename T>
std::ostream& Vector<T>::operator << (std::ostream& os, Vector<T>& v)
{
    for(int i=0;i<v.size();i++)
    {
          os << v.at(i) << " ";
    }
    return os;
}
```

Выдает вот такую ошибку:

```
'std::ostream Vector<T>::operator<<(std::ostream, const     Vector<T>&)' must take exactly one argument
std::ostream Vector<T>::operator << (std::ostream output, Vector<T> const& v)
^
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Найдите 4 отличия:

```
              friend std::ostream&           operator << (std::ostream&,   Vector<T> &);
template<typename T> std::ostream Vector<T>::operator << (std::ostream os, Vector<T> &v)
```

Comment: Поправил. Ошибка осталась
   `template<typename T1> friend std::ostream&  operator<< (std::ostream&, Vector<T1>&);

    template<typename T>
    std::ostream& Vector<T>::operator << (std::ostream& output, Vector<T>& v)`

Comment: @sm4ll_3gg вы нашли не все отличия. Кстати, в классе писать `template` то ли не надо, то ли надо писать что-то вроде `template<>` - потому что T уже объявлено.